# AQS search EWS for sent to email address

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices

I have a collection email inbox that gets notifications from multiple systems. I am able to search by subject and process successfully but would like search by the email address it was sent to because the subjects are changing and changeable. Seems to only search by Display Name, which is the name of the collection box, but I send to aliases. 
`db@domain.local`, `otherdb@domain.local`, `thisdb@domain.local`
 all point to the one collection account.

I'd like this work

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "to:'db@domain.local'", new ItemView(10));
```

and then I can setup different processing based on the sent to address.

I tried to setup a SearchFilter, but the ItemSchema doesn't seem to provide the SentTo, only the DisplayTo.

```
SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring sentToFilter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.DisplayTo, "db@domain.local", ContainmentMode.Substring, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCase);
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sentToFilter, new ItemView(10));
```

Here is what I found the search options can be in the Query
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn579420(v=exchg.150).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Moo-Juice leading me to the EmailMessageSchema I was able to find the sent to in the InternetMessageHeaders schema

```
 SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring sentToFilter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageHeaders, "db@domain.local", ContainmentMode.Substring, ComparisonMode.IgnoreCase);
 FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sentToFilter, new ItemView(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `ItemSchema`.  Consider using [`EmailMessageSchema`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessageschema_fields(v=exchg.80).aspx) which includes [`ToRecipients`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage.torecipients(v=exchg.80).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but it seemed to still be only testing for Display Names in the ToRecipients